# How to change CakePHP 3.x validation error message

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Here is validation function in CakePHP 3.x for `PostsTable`:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('title', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('title','Please fill Title field');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('content', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('content','Please add a Content');

    return $validator;
}
```

The form in `add` view is:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($post) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Post') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('content');
        echo $this->Form->input('category_id', ['options' => $categories]);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Why is the default validation message always shown instead of the `notEmpty` message?

Comment: It's probably triggering the first rule, which has no custom message. Try adding a message.

Comment: I have already tried adding custom message but it's still not working, what's the problem?

Comment: What exactly is the message that you are seeing? For which field? And what data are you submitting (if any)? Have you checked that your `validationDefault()` method is being invoked at all? Also what's the exact CakePHP version that you are using?

Comment: when i click submit button for adding new post, validationDefault() is being invoked, but my custom error message is not appearing at all, each time the default cakephp error message is shown "Please fill out this field", am using cakephp-3-1-6

Comment: Problem fixed, i renamed `validationDefault(Validator $validator)` to `validationPost(Validator $validator)`, i also  made this modification inside `PostsController add function` : `$post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data,['validate' => 'Post']);`

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed, i renamed `validationDefault(Validator $validator)` to `validationPost(Validator $validator)`, i also made this modification inside `PostsController` adding function :

```
$post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data,['validate' => 'Post']);
```